# SwiftUI: deinit equivalent?

Tags: swiftui

What is the equivalent of UIKit View's `deinit` for a SwiftUI view?

I have looked at `.onDisappear...` but, it does not seem to me that is the hook I should be using to know when a SwiftUI View is gone for good, for example during navigation etc...

Comment: There is none. You can't think of SwiftUI like it is UIKit. They are completely different. What exactly are you trying to do? Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @zumzum: A View in SwiftUI is more like value type! It get computed lot's of times! Or just 1 time like login view, So your question make no meaning about deinit of a view in SwiftUI! it is not reference type. If you want get rid of a View simple put out from render process! that is all you need! Try not thinking about SwiftUI like you are thinking about UIKit. They are deferent.

Comment: I guess I asked a stupid question. I was trying to understand who is holding on the StateObject used in a view.

Comment: SO is not for a general question like that, but is to help you fix code. Your question actually goes to the heart of the difference between UIKit and SwiftUI. We use Classes which are reference types in UIKit, and some entity has a reference to the instantiation of the class. If nothing has a reference, ARC deallocates it. In SwiftUI, we use Value Types, structs, as views. Technically, structs are immutable. We use @State to get around that, but the best way to think about it is that only the struct holds a reference to the '@State' variable, at least as a mental model.

Comment: ok, I understand what you're saying. So from what you said here I would assume that even thought I navigated away from the view, the view was still in memory since its StateObject's deinit did not run?